# iphone - MKMapView from google maps URL

Tags: iphone, mkmapview

i'm using the MKMapView first time.

I need to show some address in one MKMapView: the address (take parsing an xml file) are google maps links.

Is possible to set the coordinates of the MKMapView using the URL?
Or i need to take the longitude and latidude?

thanks

Comment: Take a look at URL schemes for apps, you can pass in values and read it as a dictionary.  You could pass in lat/lon and set the MKMapview center and zoom

Answer (score 0):

To plot a point on a MKMapView, I'm pretty sure you need the longitude & latitude of the point.

As far as I'm aware using the iPhone MKMapView & associated classes, you can do reverse geocoding (ie - convert a longitide & latitude into an address), but I think going the other way - forward geocoding (address into a longitude / latitude) is not supported.

There are plenty of services you can use though that aren't google that do forward geocoding - one of which is [Geonames](http://www.geonames.org/export/). The free service has no support contract, so it's liable to stop working without notice - but it seems to do the trick OK for small or offline operations.

Best of luck with this one!

Answer (score 0):

You have to take the longitude and latitude position of the point otherwise
you can provide address to google map service, it will provide a lat and long position in JSON or XML format(for reference see google Reverse geo coding).

http://googlemapsapi.blogspot.com/2006/06/geocoding-at-last.html

use NSMutableRequest class to find-out the lat and long,
for reference urlString-

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv", theAddress];
NSString *locationString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]] autorelease];
```

for MKMapView you can refer this blog- 
[link](http://mayurbirari.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/how-to-access-mkmapkit-in-iphone/)